# Exit from a stdout read python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, smb

How do i exit from a stdou.read() if the command that I executed enter in input mode?

Example:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('smbclient <IP>', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

if the command connect to the IP it will enter in the input mode for the smb but i only want to check if it connect or not

Comment: This just starts a subprocess, it's not stuck anywhere at all. If you just want to run the command, try `subprocess.run()` instead.

Comment: @tripleee but when i run thr command i cited the code get stuck if manage to connect and don't move

Comment: If you don't read the pipe you set up it will get stuck because of that; but if you have no intention to read the pipe, just don't set up a pipe.